# How $display works in verilog

Tags: verilog

At the point where `$display` appears in this code, there is an error. Why?

```
module always_example();
reg clk,reset,enable,q_in,data;

always @ (posedge clk)
if (reset)  begin
   data <= 0;
end else if (enable) begin   
   data <= q_in;
end
     $display("data=%d", data);   
endmodule
```

The error message is:

> 10: syntax error 10: error: invalid module item

Comment: assign value in q_in

Answer (score 2):

You need to put display within the always block.

```
module always_example();
reg clk,reset,enable,q_in,data;

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (reset)  begin
       data <= 0;
     end else if (enable) begin   
       data <= q_in;
     end

     $display("data=%d", data);
end 

endmodule
```

You still need to put an initial block to initialize the variables and change them. You also need to create a clock. Things will be a lot clearer if you look at some tutorials for Verilog and understand on how to create a test bench and a design module.

Comment: `$display` for a variable assigned with non-blocking (`<=`) will print the previous value. If you want the new value, use `$strobe`

Comment: @Greg I didn't know that since I have never used $strobe. Thanks for that tip.